# How to get two items at a time in a for loop in python?

Tags: python, for-loop

Is there a way to read two items at a time in a for loop in python? If yes, what is the best way?

For example:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for ix, i in enumerate(a):
    j = a[ix+1]
    print("i:", i, "j:", j)
```

But it will fail when `i` reaches the last item because `a[ix+1]` doesn't exist. Is there a better way which will never fail?

Comment: `for i,v in zip(a, a[1:]): print(i, v)` ?

Comment: @Rakesh is it the fastest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.zip_longest`

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import zip_longest
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
for i,v in zip_longest(a, a[1:]): 
    print(i, v)
```

**Output:**

```
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 6
6 7
7 8
8 9
9 None
```

Comment: Thanks, I wanted `i` to have value `9` and `j` to have value `None` in the end. Your answer enables this. But is using zip fast?

Comment: According to me yes, it should be

Comment: I would be glad if I could acquire index value in each for iteration.

Comment: Use `enumerate` Ex: `for idx, (i,v) in enumerate(zip_longest(a, a[1:])):`

Answer (score 1):

You can fix your code by slicing out the last item:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for ix, i in enumerate(a[:-1]):
    j = a[ix+1]
    print("i:", i, "j:", j)
```

A better way is to use `zip`:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for i, j in zip(a, a[1:]):
    print("i:", i, "j:", j)
```

Comment: Thanks, is using `zip` faster? I need speed.

Comment: Thanks, but I want `i` to be equal to `9` in the end, and `j` to have a `None` value for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the for loop, you should iterate until the -1 value:

```
for i in (a[:-1]):
    j = a[i+1]
    print("i:",i,"j:",j)
```

Comment: I had an IndexError.